# Ant SSHExec task does not return when calling Tomcat startup.sh

Tags: tomcat, ant

From my (Windows) desktop or the (Windows or Unix) Jenkins server (which I believe uses the same underlying JSch technology), I can't seem to call the startup.sh script in the Tomcat bin dir as I want to. Tomcat (7) lives on a Solaris 9 server. I have rather basic Unix knowledge.

It executes successfully (Tomcat starts fine) but never returns until the Tomcat process is killed. I imagine other similar scripts would have the same behavior.

Example ant task (the commands are the same as I would put in Jenkins "Execute shell script on remote host" build task)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="remote-tomcat-controls" basedir=".">
    <property name="hostname">someserver</property>
    <property name="username">someuser</property>
    <property name="password">somepassword</property>
    <property name="port">22</property>
    <property name="tomcathome">~/tomcat</property>
    <target name="start-tomcat">
        <sshexec   host="${hostname}" port="${port}" username="${username}" 
            password="${password}" trust="true"  
            command=". ~/.profile; cd ${tomcathome}/bin; ./startup.sh" />
    </target>
</project>
```

This starts Tomcat successfully but the task never returns unless/until the Tomcat process is killed on the server:

```
start-tomcat:
  [sshexec] Connecting to someserver:22
  [sshexec] cmd : . ~/.profile; cd ~/tomcat/bin; ./startup.sh
```

There are 3 commands involved:

- Import users profile so Java is in the path
- Change to the tomcat bin dir so relative paths to log files work
- Start Tomcat

I have tried moving these commands into a new script on the server, and have the Ant task simply call that, same results.

I have tried prepending the command with nohup and ending with &, no luck either.

Results you get when running the startup.sh script during an interactive ssh session:

```
$ ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/ebiztest/jdk1.6.0_34
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
$
```

Control is returned immediately.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**In response to the answer from 'aa vv'**
Using commandResource instead of command let me point to a local file that contains the commands to run (added more commands for demonstration):

```
pwd
. ~/.profile;java -version
pwd
java -version
pwd
cd ~/tomcat-datasheets/bin;pwd
pwd
 ./startup.sh
```

Output:

```
start-tomcat:
  [sshexec] Connecting to servername:22
  [sshexec] cmd : pwd
  [sshexec] /home/ebiztest
  [sshexec] cmd : . ~/.profile;java -version
  [sshexec] java version "1.6.0_34"
  [sshexec]
  [sshexec] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_34-b04)
  [sshexec]
  [sshexec] Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.9-b04, mixed mode)
  [sshexec]
  [sshexec] cmd : pwd
  [sshexec] /home/ebiztest
  [sshexec] cmd : java -version
  [sshexec] java version "1.4.2_04"
  [sshexec]
  [sshexec] Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_04-b05)
  [sshexec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_04-b05, mixed mode)
  [sshexec]
  [sshexec] cmd : pwd
  [sshexec] /home/ebiztest
  [sshexec] cmd : cd ~/tomcat-datasheets/bin;pwd
  [sshexec] /home/ebiztest/tomcat-datasheets/bin
  [sshexec] cmd : pwd
  [sshexec] /home/ebiztest
  [sshexec] cmd :  ./startup.sh
  [sshexec] ksh: ./startup.sh:  not found
```

It seems commands on separate lines are run entirely separately from eachother, only semicolon separated commands on the same line execute sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with `'command'` option, you have execute a command/set of commands ( 2 cases : either ; seperated commands is not supported for running single command line OR script call is not supported ).

```
<sshexec   host="${hostname}" port="${port}" username="${username}" 
            password="${password}" trust="true"  
            commandResource="wrapper_script" outputproperty="wrapper.output.prop"/>


 <echo message="${wrapper.output.prop}"/>
```

Instead of `command` use `commandResource` as specified in ant manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html to see if that helps.

wrapper_script

```
. ~/.profile
cd ${tomcathome}/bin
./startup.sh
```

Comment: The script seems to run each command in a vacuum. See my edit in the main post.

Comment: As its printing 'ksh: ./startup.sh:  not found' , whether your script is present in same working directory & is unix compatible format?. And just try to add : 'ls -l startup.sh ; dos2unix startup.sh ' before executing

Comment: The startup.sh runs fine when executed in putty, and it runs fine when the commands are chained together.

The issue here is that the "cd" command changes the directory but the next command seems to start a new session or something...it is no longer in the directory that the "cd" command changed to.

Comment: Based on comments you added, one last suggestion, try executing with subshell by grouping required commands inside parenthesis like:
 ( cd ${tomcathome}/bin; ./startup.sh )

Answer (score 0):

Try to chain the commands like that :

```
command=". ~/.profile &amp;&amp; cd ${tomcathome}/bin &amp;&amp; ./startup.sh"
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, this gets treated the same as ";"